# How to kill thread blocking on evaluating Regex - catastrophic backtracking

Tags: java, regex, multithreading

How to kill a thread which is evaluating a regex , -- this happens for catastrophic backtracking?

Is there a way to NOT use Thread.stop(), but , kill the thread.

I have tried future.cancel(true), this however does not terminate the thread, just tries to interrupt the thread.

Given the fact that this is a class:

```
public class myRegex implements Runnable
{
   public void run(){

this.evaluateRegex(pattern, matcher);  // internally calls the patterns and matcher...
}

    public void evaluateRegex(Stirng pattern, String matcher)
{
// does the code specific logic
}

}
```

How do I terminate a long going thread, which has backtracking?

Comment: I do not think, you will be able to detect backtracking at runtime...
Something perhaps is wrong with your regex...

Comment: Can you share your regex??

Answer (score 1):

> How do I terminate a long going thread, which has backtracking?

Every Backtracking has a condition to evaluate to return or call the next level.

```
if(conditionToReturn){
   return;
}
else{
    result = callRecursiveBacktrack();

}
```

There should break your design pattern with an ugly instance variable `canRun` ( synchronized or not is up to case)
something like this:

```
if (this.canRun) {
    if (conditionToReturn) {
        return;
    } else {
        result = callRecursiveBacktrack();
        if (!this.canRun) {
            return;
        }
    } 
  else {
        return;
   }
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in interruption mechanism? `this.canRun` => `Thread.interrupted();`.

Comment: @assylias is matter of prefference: 1 more boolean variable declaration and direct access or a function call, not so important imho. The desired logic will work

Comment: He must be using a pattern matcher for a particular regex. The logic is internal to the API. I don't think he will be able to change that.

Comment: @Dhrubajyoti every function can be recursive, that is other thing is correct or nt. The question it was how to stop from a recursive (backtracking)

Comment: @matheszabi That's not particularly easy if you're using a 3. party regex library, or e.g. just the regexp library from the standard class library. You do not want to rewrite and take full ownership of that.

Comment: Yes, I would be using a pattern matcher in java, isnt there a way to detect this situation before I get into matching it with the string?..  Because, this is where the thread fails. And once it starts matching , it internally hogs on memory and CPU, which can be avoided.

Comment: @Dc01_xx lets say you load 1Gb string from HDD and start matching, with a simple Java function call. On that case not an elegant way to stop it, because Java does a Just in time compile and start run, it will not return while not a result or an error. Solution , glitch exist: go to native threading override some  stuff and you can kill even the thread, (not only stop) but those are hacks, not "Java programming". Or override the regexp mathcing with adding those extra checking...